# iPad Popping Back to Page Top on Scroll

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, skrollr

I am using WordPress, Bootstrap, and `Skrollr`. I have `Skrollr` disabled on mobile using the following code:

```
var mySkrollrFunction = function () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    // initialize skrollr if the window width is large enough
    if (windowWidth > 1024) {
        skrollr.init({
            forceHeight: false,
            smoothScrolling: true,

            mobileCheck: function() {
                //hack - forces mobile version to be off
                return false;
            }
        });
     }

     // disable skrollr if the window is resized below 768px wide
    if (windowWidth <= 1024) {
         skrollr.init().destroy(); // skrollr.init() returns the singleton created above
    }
};
```

I am not using Bootstrap `scrollSpy`, but I have also not implicitly disabled it. My main issue is if I stop scrolling in the middle of the disabled `Skrollr` element, it pops back to top pretty consistently. Otherwise, it happens randomly.

Since I am relatively new to WordPress, I am not sure if this is a WordPress problem, Skrollr issue, or Bootstrap issue. How do I prevent this scroll-to-top behavior on mobile devices?

Comment: Can you post a link?

Comment: Unfortunately it's in production right now. So I don't have a link available.